# SQL Oracle: update with join statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Просьба, подсказать, как можно выполнить update c использованием несколько таблиц,
например имею запрос:

```
select t1.cul1, t1.cul2, t3.cul3, from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.cul1 = t1.cul1
left join table3 t3 on t3.cul1 = t1.cul1
where t1.cul2 = '123'
and t2.cul5 = 'er'
and t3.cul4 = 'rty'
```

как можно к такому запросу применить update

```
update table1
   set t1.cul2 = 'new value'
```

при этом сохраняя условия собранное по 2ум дополнительным таблицам,
ver: Oracle Database 12c

Comment: А что тут делает LEFT? ведь условия во WHERE превращают его в INNER...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET cul2 = 'new value'
WHERE cul2 = '123'
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table2
               WHERE table1.cul1 = table2.cul1
                 AND table2.cul5 = 'er' )
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table3
               WHERE table1.cul1 = table3.cul1
                 AND table3.cul4 = 'rty' )
```